# Can't get OpenLayers 3 map to display in Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, openlayers-3

It looks like there is a weird bug when trying to display an ol3 map within a modal. The map is in the modal but it doesn't display. Resizing the window manually forces it display however. Here's [a link](http://beta.www.ciesin.columbia.edu/mapping/ol3/ex01-stick-foot-lght.html/) to try and see what I mean. Click on the settings pulldown within each map. Click on 'Get Feature Info'. This will toggle the modal with a map in it (but not displaying). Resize your window. Voila!

I tried many ways to use javascript and jQuery to trigger a resize event along the lines of:

```
$('#featinfo').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
ol.Map.event.trigger(map5, "resize"); //borrowed from google.maps.event. How to do this in ol3?
});
```

Help?

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: no. not yet. any ideas?

Comment: Check this http://jsbin.com/hunexepeti/2/edit?html,js,output and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904425/openlayers-3-not-showing-on-a-simple-modal?rq=1

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. You need to force the map to load after the modal has been open.
Try having a function that inits the map:

```
function loadMap () {
    var map = new ol.Map({
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                collapsible: false
            })
        }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2
        })
    });
}
```

And shown.bs.modal is the event trigered once the modal is opened

```
<script>
    $('#GazModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        loadMap();
     })
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried:

```
map.updateSize();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I have experienced the exact same problem, calling the method is working for me. Can you elaborate on how you came to conclusion that it does not solve the problem?

Comment: This may not work if some interfering async job finishes after the call, so make sure this is called when other map or resizing tasks are done.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This solved the issue.
`
    window.setTimeout(function () {
            map.updateSize();
    }, 200)
`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set a height and width for the Open Layers map container..

```
#map {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/68637

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your demo doesn't display any map though. It has the same problem. ;)

Comment: I see no map either

Answer (score 0):

In the controller of my modal I create the map when the rendered promise from $modalInstance is resolved

```
$modalInstance.rendered.then(function () {
            createMap();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the creation of the modal and the map is happening almost simultaneously so when you create the map it can't find the div element to create it. I put a small timeout after the creation of the modal to solve it

```
  setTimeout(() => {
  const map2 = new Map({
    target: 'scanmap',
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({ source: new OSM() })
    ],
    view: new View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 6
    })
  });
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

In an AngularJS application i had the same problem.

I resolved it by adding a little timout on $onInit()

```
constructor(private $log: ILogService, private $window: any, private $timeout: ITimeoutService) {
}

$onInit() {

    // we need a timout here to load map after the modal!
    this.$timeout(() => {
        this.initMyMap();
    });

}
```