# OpenLayers 3 not showing on a simple modal

Tags: jquery, openlayers-3

I'm trying to display a map using OpenLayers 3 and the [SimpleModal plugin for jQuery](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/). When I click my link, the modal opens but the map isn't showing. What am I missing?

I've reproduced my problem on JSBin, http://jsbin.com/hunexepeti/2/edit?html,js,output

This is the HTML relevant part,

```
<a id="open-map" href="#">Open map</a>
<div id="map"></div>
```

and this is my JS,

```
function initMap(lat, lon) {
    var container = document.getElementById('map');
    var map = new ol.Map({ 
      layers: [ 
        new ol.layer.Tile({ 
          source: new ol.source.Stamen({
            layer: 'toner'
          })
        })
      ], 
      renderer: 'canvas',
      target: container, 
      view: new ol.View({ 
        center: [lat, lon], 
        zoom: 2 
      }) 
    }); 
  }

$(document).on('click', 'a#open-map', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var pos = {
    lat: 0,
    lon: 0
  };

  $("#map").modal({ 
    onOpen: function (dialog) {
      dialog.overlay.fadeIn('fast', function () {
        dialog.data.hide();
        dialog.container.fadeIn('fast', function () {
          dialog.data.slideDown('fast');     
        });
      });
      initMap(pos.lat, pos.lon);
    },
    onClose: function (dialog) {
      dialog.data.fadeOut('fast', function () {
        dialog.container.hide('fast', function () {
          dialog.overlay.slideUp('fast', function () {
            $.modal.close();
          });
        });
      });
    },
    overlayClose: true
  });
});
```

EDIT: It is fixed, thanks to @ekuusela answer. However I have several location links, so I need to open different locations into the modal.

- Should I reuse the same map and change its View?
- or could I create a new one with a new View because the older is overwritten? I'm curious about performance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `initMap` after the animations are finished, so in the `slideDown` animation's callback.

The `slideDown` animation of course won't show anything if you init the map after it's been completed. You could modify the `onOpen` to be something like this:

```
onOpen: function (dialog) {
  dialog.overlay.fadeIn('fast', function () {
    dialog.data.hide();
    dialog.container.fadeIn('fast', function () {
      dialog.data.show(); // show just so we can init the map properly
      initMap(pos.lat, pos.lon);
      dialog.data.hide().slideDown('fast');  
    });
  });
```

Alternatively, OpenLayers 3 might have some properties you can set to the view to make it ignore container visibility and dimensions on initialize.

Comment: Such a fool x) Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I need to open a different map location into a modal, should I reuse the same map and change its View? or should I create a new one with a new View?

Comment: Both ways would be fine. If you create a new map each time, make sure to call `map.setTarget(null)` on the old one to free resources.

Comment: Ok, but remember my map was declared inside `initMap(lat,lon)`. So, `map` variable isn't seen from outside, and I guess that neither when initMap() is called again because it would be a new `map` variable.

Comment: I should add that I'm working on the context of a Chrome Extension, in which I inject my content script after the DOM are loaded

Comment: hey, sorry, is it fine if I declare `map` as global variable in order to `setTarget(null)`? because as I told above `map` only lives inside initMap()

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution create your own modal. the html :

```
<a href="#openModal">
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
                <div>
                    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                    <div id="map" class="map" data-role="map"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

the css :
        .modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .modalDialog:target {
        opacity:1;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

```
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 3% auto;
    background: #fff;
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

initialize your openlayer :

```
function initialize(url) { document.getElementById('map') //etc //byId }
```

then you must set the height for the map in your modal :

```
function fixContentHeight(){
    var viewHeight = $(window).height();
    var maps = $("div[data-role='map']:visible:visible");

    var contentHeight = viewHeight;
    maps.height(contentHeight);
}
fixContentHeight();
```

hope it can helps...